# Multithreaded server in C (threads loss)

Tags: c, multithreading, tcp, server, pthreads

I'm struggling to solve this problem with my multi-threaded server. The server has to create a new thread for every connection and here's the code:

```
int main() {
   int client, val = 1;
   struct sockaddr_in saddr;
   socklen_t slen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

   s_sock = socket(F_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   memset( &saddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
   saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   saddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
   inet_aton(HOST, &saddr.sin_addr);
   setsockopt( s_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, sizeof(int) );
   bind(s_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &saddr, sizeof(saddr));

   listen(s_sock, MAX_CONN);

   while(1) {
      pthread_t thread;
      client = accept( s_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &saddr, &slen);
      printf("Accepted a client\n");
      pthread_create(&thread, NULL, server, (void*) &client);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is if I start several clients simultaneously, first ones get lost and the last one finishes successfully. I guess it happens because of the variable `thread` which gets rewritten when another connection is accepted.
Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Related if not a duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13794129/694576

Comment: Please elaborate more on what "*get lost*" would mean.

Comment: by "get lost" I mean that the client gets stuck - it never gets any response any more

Comment: "*it never gets any response any more*" this still is not clear to me. Who/what is "*it*", the "*lost*" tread?

Comment: I'd recommend to read about how your debugger supports debugging multithreaded programs and then deep dive in what is really going on. Threads do not "*get losts*".

Comment: OT: *There is no need to cast* an address if passed/assigned to a `void`-pointer (in C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `client` gets rewritten, not `thread`.

```
   while(1) {
      pthread_t thread;
      client = accept( s_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &saddr, &slen);
      printf("Accepted a client\n");
      pthread_create(&thread, NULL, server, (void*) &client);
   }
```

You have a race condition here. After the call to `pthread_create`, this thread will loop back and change the value of `client` with no synchronization. So what can the newly-created thread possibly do with `&client`? It can't follow the pointer to get the descriptor because this thread is about to modify `client` at some unpredictable time.

Imagine if this loop runs twice quickly with no opportunity for any other threads to run. You've now created two threads and passed them both `&client` -- the very same value. You now have two threads working the same socket and one socket lost.

Do not pass a thread the address of some variable whose value you are about to change!

Comment: You are nice describing a problem which had been described in many other answers. *If* this obvious issue would be the cause of the OP's problem, then I'd recommended to close this question as a duplicate. But we still do not know, as the question's trouble description is still to vague.

Comment: @alk The code has UB. Whether or not fixing the UB fixes the OP's issue, the OP must fix the UB! There's no point in doing much else.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is great, creating an independent array of clients' descriptors has helped. Now I need to figure out how to reuse that array, but it's a completely different task. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mishkamashka A pattern you might find useful is to `malloc` a new structure for each thread you're going to create it, fill it in with the information the thread needs, create the thread with a pointer to that structure, and let the newly-created thread `free` the structure when it's done with it. This ensures it's not modified after the thread is created and makes it easy to pass to the thread whatever information you want.